# batch rename files and overwrite if filename already exists (windows)

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, rename, file-rename

Dropbox has messed up many files in my folders, so here's the situation:
I now have 2 filenames for each file I want to keep:

1) file.*

2) file (Home-PC's conflicted copy 2014-12-04).*

The file I want to keep is the second one and I want to delete the first file so the final result will be that I only have a file called file.* (first name) with the contents of second file.
This has happened to many files in many folders and I want to batch rename all of them, REPLACING the first file.

I have tried using this powershell command found on this site on two files, a.txt and b.txt (for experimenting):

```
Get-ChildItem . -include *.txt | Move-Item -Destination { $_.name.Replace("a","b")} -Force
```

but there's no use, the powershell does nothing, and throws an error if I don's use -Force.
I don't have any experience in powershell or command prompt but I can copy/paste a command as I tried the above command.

I have also tried using another command, and failed:

```
Get-ChildItem . -include *.txt | Where-Object { $_.name -match "a$" } | Move-Item -destination { $_.name -replace "a$", "b" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you understand regular expressions, then this is fairly easy using batch, coupled with [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) - a hybrid utility that renames files by performing a regular expression search and replace on the file name. [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

I don't actually use JREN to rename, instead I hack it to derive the name where the file is to be MOVEd.

Your specification is a bit vague. The regular expression I used may need to be adjusted. Currently it looks for the last occurrence of `<OneOrMoreSpaces>(` that precedes `).<extensionText>`. It preserves all of the text before `<OneOrMoreSpaces>(`, as well as the extension.

The script below will simply print out the MOVE commands that would be executed. Remove the `ECHO` from the script to actually perform the move operations.

The script only moves a file if the original exists. If you want to always move the file, then remove `if exist "%%~dpA%%B"`

**fixDupes.bat**

```
@echo off
for /f tokens^=1^,3^ delims^=^" %%A in (
  'jren "(.*) +\(.*\)(\..*)" "$1$2" /t %*'
) do (
  if exist "%%~dpA%%B" echo move /y "%%A" "%%~dpA%%B"
)
```

To processes the current directory:

```
fixDupes
```

To process the `C:\myFolder` directory

```
fixDupes /P "C:\myFolder"
```

To recursively process `C:\myFolder` and all its children

```
fixDupes /P "C:\myFolder" /S
```

***Update:*** Actually, I think the regex for the extension may be a bit faulty since it will rename
 `name (xyz).abc.txt` to `name.abc.txt`, whereas I think perhaps it should leave the file alone. The actual extension is `.txt`, so one can argue the name should not match the template. Below is a fix that only renames files that have the `(stuff to be removed)` immediately before the true extension.

```
@echo off
for /f tokens^=1^,3^ delims^=^" %%A in (
  'jren "(.*) +\(.*\)(\..*)$" "$1$2" /t %*'
) do (
  if exist "%%~dpA%%B" echo move /y "%%A" "%%~dpA%%B"
)
```

Comment: From what I experimented using this script, it detects if the filename contains a word enclosed in a bracket? I didn't understand a single line of this code but THIS WORKS :) :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Usman - You will have to study regular expressions if you want to understand how it works. There are many tutorials on line. I've updated the answer to describe the pattern it looks for, and I've added a new version that I think may be more precise.